# How to get the item's text from the adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter, listadapter

How can I get the item's text from an adapter's listview?

In my adapter I have this code:

final ArrayList> userList =   controller.getAllUsers();

```
  if (userList.size() != 0) {

            //Set the User Array list in ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(PoliceSmsRegisterReceiver.this, userList, R.layout.view_user_entry_register,
                    new String[]{"userId", "sender", "fullname", "homeaddress", "emailaddress", "phonenumber", "password", "deviceid"},
                    new int[]{R.id.userId, R.id.viewSender, R.id.viewFName, R.id.viewHAddress, R.id.viewEAddress, R.id.viewPNumber, R.id.viewPassword, R.id.viewA_ID});

            ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

            myList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

(p.s ; controller is my sqlite db)

then this is my onclick:

```
 myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {


            }
        });
```

What I want to know is how I can toast the specific string in the adapter when clicking the specific item in the list. Example, I want to toast the viewSender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `AdapterView` and `position` provided by `setOnItemClickListener` to get any information about clicked item :

```
Toast.maketext(context,(ModelClass)parent.getItemAtPosition(position).getSpecificText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: sir, its working the other way, tnx. but can u be more specific on what getSpecificText() format is? sorry i'm a newbie sir. i really appreciated your answer. i tried                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); and it shows all the items on the itemlist. can u be more specific on the getspecifictext() sir? @AbdenaceurLichiheb

Comment: How do you populate your adapter? I suppose that there is a list of some model class that populate the adapter, and getSpecificText() is a method inside that model class that get some text ( name , description ... )

Comment: can you paste the result of parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() maybe wwe can find the attribute from there.

Comment: `code`final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList =  controller.getAllUsers();

ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(PoliceSmsRegisterReceiver.this, userList, R.layout.view_user_entry_register,
new String[]{"userId", "sender", "fullname", "homeaddress", "emailaddress", "phonenumber", "password", "deviceid"},
new int[]{R.id.userId, R.id.viewSender, R.id.viewFName, R.id.viewHAddress, R.id.viewEAddress, R.id.viewPNumber, R.id.viewPassword, R.id.viewA_ID});
ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

 myList.setAdapter(adapter);`code` @AbdenaceurLichiheb

Comment: it shows first toast with 0

then second toast {sender =+8080,phonenumber=8888,emailaddress=jejotom96@gmail.com .... and so on}   @AbdenaceurLichiheb

Comment: Ok then after parent.getItemAtPosition(position) add .parameterName for example parent.getItemAtPosition(position).emailaddress will show that email address, choose the parameter you want.

Comment: its red :( cannot resolve symbol. @AbdenaceurLichiheb

Comment: Of course, because you need to cast it to your model class like i did in my answer ((ModelClass)parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).emailaddress

Comment: What's your model class you are using to populate the adapter?

Comment: i dont have a model class sir. i use direct input to the adapter, the code is on the top comment @AbdenaceurLichiheb

Comment: @JohnEdgarOtom Please post the code of your SimpleAdapter in your question.

Comment: its on the question sir, after the if statement. @AbdenaceurLichiheb

Comment: Oh you are using ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>, I didn't pay attention, call it like this parent.getItemAtPosition(position).get("emailaddres")

Comment: should arraylist hashmap be declared again? cuz its getting red on the get function @Abdenaceur Lichiheb

Comment: No you just need to cast it to (HashMap<String, String>) this the code : ((HashMap<String, String>)parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).get("emailaddress")

Comment: YOUR THE MAN!! @AbdenaceurLichiheb i hope i can be like you pro coders! tnx man. it works finally. sorry newbie coder :)

Comment: You welcome you need to work more on your java skill if you want to develop android applications, please up-vote my answer if it helped you.

Comment: it says, it does not show publicity of up vote sir for below 15 badge. but it does count, just it does not show

Comment: I see you need at least 15 reputation to up-vote answers, but no problem enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use int position like this.

Toast.maketext(context,String.valueof(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: i tried this sir, Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(deviceid),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); but it toasts null output @ maulik

Comment: You have to write String.valueof(position) not device id

Comment: yes sir i've tried it, and it show the position of my adapter, what i want sir is to toast texts on my adapter, example, the deviceid. thank u btw for help sir. @maulik

Comment: What is your R.id.viewA_ID?

Comment: Android_ID sir @maulik , basically this texts came from a text msg and saved into my sqlite, then retrieve it putting in my adapter.

Answer (score 0):

An OnItemClickListener handles clicking a list item.
 You have to use  a custom adapter in which you grab hold of all the Views in the row in getView() and set onClickListeners on them there.

Comment: tnx for the advice sir @maulik, i'll try search for that.

Comment: Check out this link .    http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html